# Text not vertically aligned to the top

Tags: vertical-alignment

Basically I have the problem seen in the image below (sorry for blurring the text, but the problem should be easily seen). I have a section, followed by some text, and then on the next page a figure is right at the beginning, and then a new section right after, so no extra text available to go onto this page I imagine.

And as you can see the white space between the section title and the text just looks stupid. Any idea how to fix this ? I would much rather that all next were aligned at the top, and then the white space was at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom` and if that doesn't work, please post a MWE.

Comment: Try adding to your preamble the directive `\raggedbottom` (the default is `flushbottom`).

Comment: The \raggedbottom worked like a charm.
Write an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I'm sure it already has been written somewhere (but I don't know where).